# How to replace part of a word within a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm scraping tweets from twitter and I'm trying to clean the data. I've managed to clean most of it except for \n which occurs like this "this is my tweet\nI really like my tweet.

I've tried using `tweet_text = re.sub(r'\n','. ', tweet_text)` to replace \n with a `" ."` but I think this only remove occurrences of \n within a string not when it occurs between two words.

Any advice on how to proceed would be great.

Comment: no it works. Show your problems with an example that everyone can check. What's wrong with `str.replace` BTW?

Comment: Aren't all occurances between two words also within the string?

Comment: are you sure that the actual `\n` string isn't present (backslash then n)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The problem with string replace is that I have 1000's of tweets which means lots of different instance of different variations of which words occur around \n. Also yes I am positive as \n is for new line in a tweet and does not have any white space around it.

And Remo Yes, but bare in mind that I said tweets and not just one tweet which means I would have to write the code I posted for each individual tweet at which point it would be easier to just delete it one by one from the .CSV file.

Comment: create a [mcve] showing what doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

this should do the trick:

```
result = ''
tweet = 'this is my tweet\nI really like my tweet.'
for _ in tweet:
    if _ == r'\\' and tweet[tweet.index(_)+1] == 'n':
        result += '. '
    elif _ == 'n' and tweet[tweet.index(_)-1] == r'\\':
        continue
    else:
        result += _
```